# Maven build failure - Eclipse plugin - Tycho

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I was trying to build eclipse plug-in using Tycho and while executing following command

```
mvn org.codehaus.tycho:maven-tycho-plugin:generate-poms -DgroupId=tycho.demo -Dtycho.targetPlatform=D:\practice\java\eclipse_galilio
```

I got error like

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.codehaus.plexus.PlexusContainer.lookup(Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
```

can anyone tell me what should be done to resolve this error. I am stuck at this point and not able to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of maven are you running? Tycho requires Maven 3. I can get that error trying to run on maven 2.1.0.

Comment: What is the output of `mvn --version` ? If it's not the maven version,  are you forcing an older version of plexus or something in your pom? Here's output of when I run with maven 2.1.0 then switch to maven 3.0.1 (yes the 3.0.1 fails, but because I'm running in an empty directory, not for the missing method): http://pastebin.com/YuxbQ0i7

Comment: oops my mistake. I checked the system path again and found maven 2 was configured and not maven 3. I changed the path and it worked well. Thanks ach_I